# How to get the value of json object in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter framework to develop my website. Currently I'm sending an AJAX request using jQuery to get data from the server. I have tried two ways one the data is in a PHP associative array and the other one in a JSON object. Please see the data that I get returned from the AJAX request:

```
{
    "o": [
        {
            "q_id": "83",
            "t_id": "4",
            "question": "jjjjs.jfdaskldjf",
            "option1": "jjjjasdfasdf",
            "option2": "jjj",
            "option3": "lll",
            "option4": "lll",
            "answer": "lll",
            "marks": "22"
        },
        {
            "q_id": "84",
            "t_id": "4",
            "question": "This is testing",
            "option1": "2",
            "option2": "7",
            "option3": "8",
            "option4": "9",
            "answer": "2",
            "marks": "2"
        },
        {
            "q_id": "85",
            "t_id": "4",
            "question": "hello this is another test",
            "option1": "a",
            "option2": "b",
            "option3": "c",
            "option4": "d",
            "answer": "a",
            "marks": "2"
        },
        {
            "q_id": "86",
            "t_id": "4",
            "question": "another test",
            "option1": "8",
            "option2": "9",
            "option3": "0",
            "option4": "1",
            "answer": "1",
            "marks": "2"
        },
        {
            "q_id": "87",
            "t_id": "4",
            "question": "last question ",
            "option1": "z",
            "option2": "x",
            "option3": "c",
            "option4": "v",
            "answer": "c",
            "marks": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm accessing it as:

```
alert(data["o"][0]);
```

But the error that occurs is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Can anyone give me some suggestions as to how I can get the value or store the object in an array.

Comment: Can you post the jQuery code which makes the ajax request to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("content-type:application/json");
```

---

- is sent by the server with your json ?

---

next check :

---

- using $.getJSON or $.ajax with`datatype='json'`

---

finally,
then to access your object `data.o['0'].q_id`

Comment: Still not working if i write the header in my page where i get the data the page show the html i m using codeigniter framework. I jave try data.o['0'].q_id and data.o['0']['q_id']. but still not working now where i can add the header in view file or in controller?

Comment: Thanks mikakun now its working i only add dataType:'json' in ajax function now i get my data in object form thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

since o here is an object ad not an array..use `.`

try this

```
alert(data.o[0])
```

use loop `$.each` function to get the value of objects inside `o`

```
data.o[0].each(function(i,v){
   console.log(v.q_id);
});
```

Comment: This is my function that is call on ajax request and it return the data that is shown in question. I try alert(data.o[0]); but still get the same error.
public function getQuestions(){
   $this->includeDB();
   
   $qId = $this->input->POST('id');
   
   $array = $this->userDBclass->getQuestions($qId);
   $data['o'] = $array;
   echo json_encode($data);
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

try to use Std Object to catch send JSON to your javascript code

my code like:

var model = new StdObject();
model->blabla = "something";

return model;